Whatsapp Flow Run issue (Flow sending failed)
When trying to send flow, I received this message:
enter image description here
{
    "version": "5.1",
    "screens": [
        {
            "id": "DETAILS",
            "title": "Get help",
            "data": {},
            "terminal": true,
            "success": true,
            "layout": {
                "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "type": "Form",
                        "name": "form",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextInput",
                                "name": "name",
                                "label": "Name",
                                "input-type": "text",
                                "required": true
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "TextInput",
                                "label": "Order number",
                                "name": "orderNumber",
                                "input-type": "number",
                                "required": true
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "RadioButtonsGroup",
                                "label": "Choose a topic",
                                "name": "topicRadio",
                                "data-source": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "0",
                                        "title": "Orders and payments"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "1",
                                        "title": "Maintenance"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "2",
                                        "title": "Delivery"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "3",
                                        "title": "Returns"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "4",
                                        "title": "Other"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "required": true
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "TextArea",
                                "label": "Description of issue",
                                "required": false,
                                "name": "description"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Footer",
                                "label": "Done",
                                "on-click-action": {
                                    "name": "complete",
                                    "payload": {
                                        "name": "${form.name}",
                                        "orderNumber": "${form.orderNumber}",
                                        "topicRadio": "${form.topicRadio}",
                                        "description": "${form.description}"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}


To be able to send WA Flows you need to verify your business and maintain a high message quality.
See details here.
